# Probability of $r$ people in between

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

The question is as follows, I will append my solution as well. I have a suspicious feeling that my approach is utterly wrong.

> Mike and Tom are among $n$ people who are arranged at random in a line. What is the probability that exactly $r$ people stand between them?

**My solution:**
$$A= \{\text{Exactly }r\text{ people stand between Mike and Tom}\}$$
So $n(S)=(n+2)!$ where $n+2$ stands for Mike, Tom and the $n$ other people.
$$n(A)=2\binom nr(n-r)!r!$$
Hence the probability is
$$P(A)=\frac{2\binom{n}{r}(n-r)!r!}{(n+2)!}$$
Is there any problem with my solution? I actually worry about the numerator part.

Edit: Edited the question from the previous clarification edit. Question actually includes Mike and Tom *in* n people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are $n$ people in total and consider the picture:

$$
\underbrace{*\cdots *}_k\textrm{M}\underbrace{*\cdots*}_r\textrm{T}\underbrace{*\cdots *}_{n-r-k-2}
$$

for $0 \leq k \leq n - r - 2$. There are $n - r - 1$ possible locations for Mike. Flipping the location of Mike and Tom gives $2(n  -r - 1)$ possibilities. There are $(n - 2)!$ possibilities for the remaining people. Hence, there are $2(n - r - 1)(n - 2)!$ possible configurations. Thus the probability is

$$
\frac{2(n-r-1)(n-2)!}{n!} = \frac{2(n - r- 1)}{n(n-1)}
$$

Comment: I once thought there were $n$ people _in all_. Then I edited the question, since I noticed the attempted answer implied $n+2$ people. Apparently you were working on the old version. Please correct?

Comment: It's an easy change, just change the n to n + 2 in the equation.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Actually my attempt misled you to count Mike and Tom as extra people $(n+2)$. I reedited the question so that the original meaning still holds. Mine clearly overcounts..

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to arrange just Mike and Tom is $^n\!P_2=n(n-1)$. If there are $r$ people between them ($0\le r\le n-2$) there are $n-r-1$ ways to pick *where* the first of them will go, then two ways to pick *who* goes into that first slot. In both cases the number of ways to arrange the other people remains the same, so the answer is
$$\frac{2(n-r-1)}{n(n-1)}$$
Your approach fails to consider the $r$ in-between people being able to occupy any part of the line, which generates the $n-r-1$ factor.